# Exponential distribution problem

Tags: probability

Suppose that waiting times for M103 buses are independent and exponentially distributed with the same parameter. On average, there are 4 buses per hour.

(a) What is the probability that there are no buses for 30 minutes?

This is clearly an exponential random variable with $\lambda$ = 4 per hr.

$P(X > .5) = 1 - P(X \leq .5) = 1 - F(X) = 1 - (1-e^{(-4) * .5}) = e^{-2} = .135$

(b) What is the probability that in 2 hours you see more than 6 buses?

This I'm not sure about. Does lambda vary here?

$P(Y > 6) = 1 -P(Y \leq 6) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^6 (1-e^{- (\lambda/i) * 2})=1 - \sum_{i=1}^6 (1-e^{(- 4/i) * 2})$

(c) What is the probability that the fifth bus appears not earlier than in 1.5 hours?

$\lambda = 4/5 $ ; Every success (i.e. 5 buses) occurs 4/5 per hour.

$P(X>1.5)=1-P(X \leq 1.5)= 1 - (1-e^{(-4/5) * .1.5}) =e^{-1.2} = .301$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of buses during time period $t$. Since the waiting time is exponential with parameter $\lambda$, then $X$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$:
$$
{\rm P}\{X=k\}=\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}.
$$

1. $t=0.5,k=0$;
2. $t=2,k>6$;
3. $t=1.5,k<5$.